# How to merge those two shaders?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I've found some sort of manga shader over the internet which is great for one of my projects. I only have a small issue due to my lack of knowledge on shaders and nodes.

Instead of the pinkish color you can see under the black shadow on the left of the image, I'd like to have the face featured on the right. The pinkish color comes from the shader and the face is an image texture.
[image]
[image]

How can I do that ?

In addition, what is the best way to also add a bump node to this whole thing ?

Here's what the shader looks like :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]